# I want to shuffle the data coming from firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase, kotlin, shuffle

I am getting data from the firebase from starting to end by sequence and I want to show the data randomly but I am having issue to shuffle the data coming from the firebase. I am getting data from the firebase from starting to end by sequence and I want to show the data randomly but I am having issue to shuffle the data coming from the firebase.
Here is my code to understand it better.

Main Activity:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    lateinit var viewPager2:ViewPager2
    lateinit var adapter:VideoAdapter

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        /**set fullscreen*/
        window.setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN)

        /**set find id*/
        viewPager2 = findViewById(R.id.vpager)

        /**set database*/
        val mDataBase = Firebase.database.getReference("videos")

        val options = FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<VideoModel>()
            .setQuery(mDataBase,VideoModel::class.java)
            .build()


        /**set adapter*/
        adapter = VideoAdapter(options)
        viewPager2.adapter = adapter

    }

    override fun onStart() {
        super.onStart()
        adapter.startListening()
    }

    override fun onStop() {
        super.onStop()
        adapter.stopListening()
    }


}
```

VideoAdapter

```
class VideoAdapter(options: FirebaseRecyclerOptions<VideoModel?>) :
    FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<VideoModel?, VideoAdapter.MyViewHolder?>(options) {

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MyViewHolder, position: Int, model: VideoModel) {
        holder.setdata(model)
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): MyViewHolder {
        val view: View = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.single_video_row, parent, false)
        return MyViewHolder(view)
    }

    inner class MyViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
        var videoView: VideoView
        var title: TextView
        var desc: TextView
        var pbar: ProgressBar
        var fav :ImageView
        var isFav = false

        fun setdata(obj: VideoModel) {
            videoView.setVideoPath(obj.url)
            title.setText(obj.title)
            desc.setText(obj.desc)

            videoView.setOnPreparedListener { mediaPlayer ->
                pbar.visibility = View.GONE
                mediaPlayer.start()
            }
            videoView.setOnCompletionListener { mediaPlayer -> mediaPlayer.start() }
            fav.setOnClickListener {
                if (!isFav){
                    fav.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_fill_favorite)
                    isFav = true

                }
                else{
                    fav.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_favorite)
                    isFav = false
                }

            }
        }

        init {
            videoView = itemView.findViewById<View>(R.id.videoView) as VideoView
            title = itemView.findViewById<View>(R.id.textVideoTitle) as TextView
            desc = itemView.findViewById<View>(R.id.textVideoDescription) as TextView
            pbar = itemView.findViewById<View>(R.id.videoProgressBar) as ProgressBar
            fav = itemView.findViewById(R.id.favorites) as ImageView
            count = itemView.findViewById(R.id.count) as TextView
        }

    }
}
```

VideoModel

```
data class VideoModel( 
    var title:String?=null,
    var desc:String?=null,
    var url:String?=null
)
```

[Here are the data which i want to get randomly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZxKtG.png)

Comment: What type of random data you required. I think you can modify the Adapter code to display random data in onBindViewHolder based on postion.

Comment: Inside onBindViewHolder var updatedModel = model[rnd.nextInt(model.length)];

Comment: Or you can try on option which you are setting over adapter. Then send updatedOptions to adapter
adapter = VideoAdapter(options)

Comment: Please check the duplicate to see how you can get random elements.